# Json parameter didn't take the data that I give it

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm getting data from controller as json and I'm using the data in a Google chart, but the problem is the parameter didn't take the value that I passed in.

The url in json returning

```
https://localhost:44396/api/Chart?A='VAL1'&A='VAL2'
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:44396/api/Chart?A='VAL1','VAL2'
```

and I passed the A in parameter as :

```
A="'VAL1','VAL2'"
```

Comment: With this url,parameter ( A="'VAL1','VAL2'"),  they can be passed into controller locally. This parameter ( A='VAL1'&A='VAL2 ) can only map the first. Can you share how to send data to the background and the code to receive data in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see your code, but you should URL encode the parameter:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("'VAL1','VAL2'")
```